# Cannot reproduce the prediction made by arima

Tags: r, time-series

I wanted to manually check the prediction made by the function `arima` and got different results. Following is a simple AR(1)-example:

```
set.seed(123)
D<-rnorm(7)
> D
[1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.71506499  0.46091621

M<-arima(D,order=c(1,0,0))
predict(M)
> predict(M)$pred[1]
[1] 0.4748763
# So, the one-step-ahead prediction is: 0.4748763

# I tried to calculate this manually using the intercept:M$coef[2] and the slope multiplied with the last observation: M$coef[1]*( 0.46091621)
M$coef[2]+M$coef[1]*( 0.46091621)
0.3863168 
# As can be seen, the result now is: 0.3863168
```

Can someone tell me how to get the same result "maually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, good question. The basic problem is that the coefficient that R's authors call the `"intercept"` would be more accurately identified as the `"mean"`.

Here is how you can perform the calculations by hand

```
b <- coef(M)
b[[2]] +  b[[1]]*(D[7] - b[[2]])
# [1] 0.4748763
```

and [here is a nice discussion](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/Rissues.htm) of this very topic by the authors of ["Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples"](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/).

Comment: The reason is probably that `arima` first demeans the data.. I think I have read it somewhere but didn't consider it before...

Comment: @RStudent -- That sounds about right, and is probably even desirable for reasons touched on pp. 2-3 of Venables' famous ["Exegeses on linear models" (warning, pdf)](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf). In that case, though, the term "intercept" does end up being a bit misleading.